# Responsive Bootstrap Navbar - more than one link per row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've searched extensively for this with no existing solution. The responsive navbar for bootstrap becomes 'responsive' by making each link appear on a single row, as so:

```
|Link                |
|Link                |
|Link                |
|Link                |
```

There is a huge amount of excess space when I do this, and ideally I'd rather have it horizontally stack the menu if there is room available:

```
|Link      | Link      |
|Link      | Link      |
```

I'm not bothered about using the collapse functionality to initially hide the menu with the option to expand on small devices (although if implemented it would just collapse/expand with more than one link per row as above), but I cannot find any way to make the navbar items stack horizontally in the way that I want.

Comment: that could sounds stupid what i will say, but maybe you don't need a navbar if you don't consider it's collapse feature.

Comment: What I mean is that the solution should not be contingent on also having the collapse feature work.

Comment: so you can build your own with that flexibility that you need, like `col-xs-12` (for each link) - show in one column or `col-sm-6` (for each link) - show in two columns...

Comment: On a small device those links are blocks so that they are easily clickable, putting them in two columns on 240 px wide devices (small Androids) would be very annoying for the user. You can write a new menu css which starts the min-widths earlier and stack them from small to large, making the mobile be two columns, by using inline-block and making them 50% of the width. Pain in the arse, but doable.